# Getting "need path to queries.json" error when trying to run Google Speech Recognition java example

Tags: java, json, google-bigquery, google-speech-api

I am trying to run the java streaming speech recognition example here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-mic-recognize-java

I created a new gradle project in Eclipse, added `compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:1.1.0'` and `compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:1.70.0'` to the dependencies, and then copied in the example code from the link to the main class. Nothing from that second dependency is used in the example script that I can see, but I need it in there, otherwise I get an error like this: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.cloud.bigquery.benchmark.Benchmark`

Upon run with both dependencies added, I get the error in the title (`need path to queries.json`) immediately and the app exits. What is the queries.json file and how can I provide the application a path to it to get the example project to run? The google API is set up with proper environment variables on my system and API calls are configured to be allowed from the IP of the machine I am working on.

Here is the entire class script (only script in the project):

```
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientStream;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ResponseObserver; 
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.StreamController;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionAudio;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeResponse;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionAlternative;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionResult;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionResult;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeRequest;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse; 
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info; 
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;


public class GoogleSpeechRecognition {
    /** Performs microphone streaming speech recognition with a duration of 1 minute. */
    public static void streamingMicRecognize() throws Exception {

      ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responseObserver = null;
      try (SpeechClient client = SpeechClient.create()) {

        responseObserver =
            new ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse>() {
              ArrayList<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();

              public void onStart(StreamController controller) {}

              public void onResponse(StreamingRecognizeResponse response) {
                responses.add(response);
              }

              public void onComplete() {
                for (StreamingRecognizeResponse response : responses) {
                  StreamingRecognitionResult result = response.getResultsList().get(0);
                  SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
                  System.out.printf("Transcript : %s\n", alternative.getTranscript());
                }
              }

              public void onError(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(t);
              }
            };

        ClientStream<StreamingRecognizeRequest> clientStream =
            client.streamingRecognizeCallable().splitCall(responseObserver);

        RecognitionConfig recognitionConfig =
            RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                .build();
        StreamingRecognitionConfig streamingRecognitionConfig =
            StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setConfig(recognitionConfig).build();

        StreamingRecognizeRequest request =
            StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                .setStreamingConfig(streamingRecognitionConfig)
                .build(); // The first request in a streaming call has to be a config

        clientStream.send(request);
        // SampleRate:16000Hz, SampleSizeInBits: 16, Number of channels: 1, Signed: true,
        // bigEndian: false
        AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(16000, 16, 1, true, false);
        DataLine.Info targetInfo =
            new Info(
                TargetDataLine.class,
                audioFormat); // Set the system information to read from the microphone audio stream

        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(targetInfo)) {
          System.out.println("Microphone not supported");
          System.exit(0);
        }
        // Target data line captures the audio stream the microphone produces.
        TargetDataLine targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
        targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        targetDataLine.start();
        System.out.println("Start speaking");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Audio Input Stream
        AudioInputStream audio = new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine);
        while (true) {
          long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
          byte[] data = new byte[6400];
          audio.read(data);
          if (estimatedTime > 60000) { // 60 seconds
            System.out.println("Stop speaking.");
            targetDataLine.stop();
            targetDataLine.close();
            break;
          }
          request =
              StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                  .setAudioContent(ByteString.copyFrom(data))
                  .build();
          clientStream.send(request);
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
      responseObserver.onComplete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53026314/1031958 which was asked 6 months ago with no response from Google engineers, @Graham Polley. I suggest to try and ask them via their other support channels

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so for me it turned out to be something simple and my fault. The default run configuration was set incorrectly to one of the google classes instead of whatever you called your test class containing the example code. This is what caused both the bigquery error and the queries.json error. Just correct the main class to your test class with the example code and it works. Also, you don't need to include `compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:1.70.0'` in your gradle dependencies at all, the error that complained about needing it was caused by incorrect main class setting in run configuration.

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFTi5.png)